# Run time error : Method 'SetSourceData of object '_chart' failed while attempting to create multiple pivot charts from pivot tables

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to generate 2 charts based on a pivot table with data pulled from a microsoft access table with conditions and filters based on button click, however everytime i tried to run a macro for a button script for the 2nd button i get the error on the title.

This is the code that is not functioning

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim sh As Shape
Dim ch As Chart
Dim pc As PivotCache
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim NameString As String
Dim Pf As PivotField
Dim NumFilter As Integer

NameString = "Department Comparison" & " " & TextBox1.Value
Set pc = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Sheet1.Name & "!" & Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)

Set ws = Worksheets.Add
ws.Name = NameString

Range("A3").Select

Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=ActiveCell, TableName:=NameString)

pt.AddFields RowFields:="Ms", PageFields:="Y", ColumnFields:="D"


pt.AddDataField pt.PivotFields("RT"), Function:=XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum

pt.AddDataField pt.PivotFields("ORT"), Function:=XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum

pt.AddDataField pt.PivotFields("EA"), Function:=XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum

pt.AddDataField pt.PivotFields("PA"), Function:=XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum

pt.DataFields(1).NumberFormat = "#,##0"

Set ws = Worksheets(NameString)
Set sh = ws.Shapes.AddChart2(XlChartType:=XlChartType.xlLine, Left:=300, Top:=500, Width:=500, Height:=500)
Set ch = sh.Chart
Set pt = ws.PivotTables(1)

ch.SetSourceData pt.TableRange2

Set Pf = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(NameString).PivotFields("Y")

Pf.CurrentPage = TextBox1.Value


pt.PivotFields("Ms").AutoSort Order:=xlAscending, Field:="Sum of ORT"


Set pc = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Sheet2.Name & "!" & Sheet2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)


Range("J3").Select

Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=ws.Cells(3, 11), TableName:=NameString & " Employees")

pt.AddFields RowFields:="Month", PageFields:="Year", ColumnFields:="Department"

pt.AddDataField pt.PivotFields("RT"), Function:=XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum



pt.DataFields(1).NumberFormat = "#,##0"

Set ws = Worksheets(NameString)
Set sh = ws.Shapes.AddChart2(XlChartType:=XlChartType.xlLine, Left:=800, Top:=500, Width:=500, Height:=500)
Set ch = sh.Chart
Set pt = ws.PivotTables(NameString & " Employees")

ch.SetSourceData pt.TableRange2     ///This is where the debugger points at the error

Set Pf = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(NameString & " Employees").PivotFields("Year")

Pf.CurrentPage = TextBox1.Value
End Sub
```

I had the first button with almost the same code with the exceptionfor setting the current page fields and it worked fine but this is the one that had issues,i compared both side to side and they are 99% the same

First button click code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim sh As Shape
Dim ch As Chart
Dim pc As PivotCache
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim NameString As String
Dim Pf As PivotField
Dim NumFilter As Integer

NameString = ComboBox2.Value & " " & TextBox1.Value
Set pc = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Sheet1.Name & "!" & Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)

Set ws = Worksheets.Add
ws.Name = NameString

Range("A3").Select

Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=ActiveCell, TableName:=NameString)

pt.AddFields RowFields:="Ms", PageFields:=Array("D", "Y")


pt.AddDataField pt.PivotFields("RT"), Function:=XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum

pt.AddDataField pt.PivotFields("ORT"), Function:=XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum

pt.AddDataField pt.PivotFields("EA"), Function:=XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum

pt.AddDataField pt.PivotFields("PA"), Function:=XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum

pt.DataFields(1).NumberFormat = "#,##0"

Set ws = Worksheets(NameString)
Set sh = ws.Shapes.AddChart2(XlChartType:=XlChartType.xlLine, Left:=300, Top:=500, Width:=500, Height:=500)
Set ch = sh.Chart
Set pt = ws.PivotTables(1)

ch.SetSourceData pt.TableRange2

Set Pf = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(NameString).PivotFields("Y")

Pf.CurrentPage = TextBox1.Value

Set Pf = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(NameString).PivotFields("D")

Pf.CurrentPage = ComboBox2.Value

pt.PivotFields("Ms").AutoSort Order:=xlAscending, Field:="Sum of ORT"

NameString = ComboBox2.Value & " " & TextBox1.Value
Set pc = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Sheet2.Name & "!" & Sheet2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)


Range("J3").Select

Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=ws.Cells(3, 11), TableName:=NameString & " Employees")

pt.AddFields RowFields:="Month", PageFields:="Year", ColumnFields:="Department"

pt.AddDataField pt.PivotFields("RT"), Function:=XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum



pt.DataFields(1).NumberFormat = "#,##0"

Set ws = Worksheets(NameString)
Set sh = ws.Shapes.AddChart2(XlChartType:=XlChartType.xlLine, Left:=800, Top:=500, Width:=500, Height:=500)
Set ch = sh.Chart
Set pt = ws.PivotTables(NameString & " Employees")

ch.SetSourceData pt.TableRange2

Set Pf = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(NameString & " Employees").PivotFields("Year")

Pf.CurrentPage = TextBox1.Value

Set Pf = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(NameString & " Employees").PivotFields("Department")

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(NameString & " Employees").PivotFields("Department")
For i = 1 To .PivotItems.Count - 1
.PivotItems(.PivotItems(i).Name).Visible = False
Next i

End With

Pf.PivotItems(ComboBox2.Value).Visible = True


End Sub
```

Comment: Im using the pagefields to filter out to show for specific years for the chart

Comment: It is part of the table for the chart,it is just that i am filtering out the years on the table then extracting the table data to create the chart based on the code

Comment: Untested, but does `TableRange1` fail?

Comment: I tested it just now,it still fails on the button2 _click code